# Seam2.2 migration to 2.3 produce org.jboss.seam.core.init.jndiPattern or use @JndiName error

Tags: seam, jboss7.x, seam2

I'm currently working on migrating from Seam 2.2 to 2.3.

I'm following the guide from here: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/migration23.html and is now testing the migrated app.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must specify org.jboss.seam.core.init.jndiPattern or use @JndiName:
```

In my components.xml I've tried 2 approach:

1. Use core:init:

   ```
   <core:init debug="@debug@" jndi-pattern="@seam_jndiPattern@" />
   //where seam_jndiPattern=java:app/myApp-ejb.jar/#{ejbName}
   ```
2. Listing the Stateless beans:

   ```
   <component class="org.service.admin.impl.AccountService"
           jndi-name="java:app/myApp-ejb/AccountService" />

   @Stateless
   @Name("accountService")
   @AutoCreate
   public class AccountService{
   }
   ```

But both produced:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must specify org.jboss.seam.core.init.jndiPattern or use @JndiName: accountService
```

But when I tried to add `@JndiName` annotation to the stateless session bean, the error was resolved, but I don't want to add the annotation on each class because I have hundreds of them. Any possible workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `components.xml` change `core:init` to

```
<core:init debug="true" jndi-pattern="java:app/**your-ejb-name**/#{ejbName}" />
```

or use `@JndiPattern` annotation in your beans.

```
@JndiName("java/jboss:phoenix-ejb/**yourClassName**")
```

In your case it would be

```
@JndiName("java/jboss:phoenix-ejb/**AccountService**")
```

Comment: Yes, @JndiName works thanks. But we abandoned the migration to seam2.3 and is now trying javaee6 :-)